# Close an extra iOS web app window in standalone web app

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, iphone-standalone-web-app

When a new browser window is opened with `window.open()`, the same window can be closed with `window.close()`. That works on all the browsers I have on my laptop, and it works in Safari on my iPhone (iOS 7).

However, if I save the very same web app to the iPhone home screen, it stops working.

That is sad because I initially added this feature *just for this situation*. Without this extra close feature, there is no way to get back to the original web app in my situation (I don't control the content of the opened page).

**How can a page opened through javascript be closed through javascript in a iOS standalone web app?**

Surprised by the lack of answers, I am now opting for a *workaround*. I suspect `window.open()` doesn't really open a new window in standalone mode, but replace the original page. Therefore, I now detect standalone and just replace the `window.close` with another `window.open` that re-opens the calling page.

If you know it better - please comment or answer!

Comment: I suspect the behaviour you describe is also the reason why the Dropbox chooser (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) doesn't work if the host app is launched from the home screen - the chooser page opens, but never closes.

Comment: This appears to be working for me.  I am using localStorage to pass forward a value that I need from the first page to the second.  I could conceivably use cookies, but whatever.